# In Xcode 14 & iOS 16 purple warnings starting with 'This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.'

Tags: wkwebview, ios16, xcode14

When loading the URL in WKWebView, it leads to a *security* warning and later app gets crashes.

Warning in UIApplicationMain -

> This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.

[image: Security Warning in WKWebview]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: got same issue, seems it apple bug

Comment: same exact issue, anyone would be able to solve this? Putting web views certificate validation on DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { } doesn't help.

Comment: same issue as I wrapped a WKWebView in `UIViewRepresentable`. I've also changed the code running by `WKNavigationDelegate`calls to dispatch on main. Still getting this.

Answer (score 41):

Good in-depth reply from an [Apple employee on the forums.](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467?answerId=734799022#734799022)

> The poor interaction between WKWebView, Security framework, and this Xcode feature is a known issue (r. 94019453). We plan to address it at some point but I don’t have any info to share as to when that’ll happen.

Answer (score 18):

Apparently, it is either an Xcode bug or an unnecessary "perfect optimization" notification.

As I'm writing, there isn't any reported solution on the Apple developer website.

You can see a good discussion on *[UI unresponsiveness" warning on @main](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712074)*.